# Conditional Route not rendering the redirected Layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In `AppRouter`, I have a conditional route with redirect for `<AdminLayout/>`.

relevant snippet:

```
<Route
          exact
          path="/admin"
          strict
          render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
        >
          {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/admin/summary" /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
```

If `loggedIn` is true then, redirect to `/admin/summary` else redirect it back to `<Login/>`

The problem is: it is only changing the URL but not rendering the `<AdminLayout/>`.

Not sure where I am going wrong and what I am missing.

**UPDATED PrivateRoute and AppRouter below**

`AppRouter`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

import { alertActions } from "../actions";
import { history } from "../helpers";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth/Auth.js";
import ResetPassword from "../components/pages/reset-password/ResetPassword";
import MailReset from "../components/pages/reset-password/MailReset";
import PrivateRoute from "../routes/PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = () => {
  const alert = useSelector((state) => state.alert);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        {/* <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} /> */}
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin">
          <Dashboard />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <Route
          path="/auth/login"
          render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />}
        />
        <Route exact path="/auth/forgotPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/auth/mail_reset" component={MailReset} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/auth/login" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

`PrivateRoute`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import AdminLayout from "../layouts/Admin/Admin";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, roles, ...rest }) {
  console.log("rest pvt route", ...rest);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        console.log("propsssss", props);
        // if (!localStorage.getItem('userid')) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
          // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/auth/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          );
        }

        // logged in so return component
        return <AdminLayout {...props} />;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default { PrivateRoute };
```

Comment: Its because you are using both `render` and `children` simultaneously. This [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) help you how to add `AuthRoutes`. If still doesn't understand let me know will add sandbox then.

Comment: thanks for the example. I had written a `PrivateRoute` component but couldn't get it to work. So, then I was trying this out. Can you please sandbox it. I have also updated the description with my `PrivateRoute` component, in case it comes handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So trying to explain what its is wrong:

1. You are setting rendering `child` and `render props` that's why `children` props takes priority here:

```
<Route
          exact
          path="/admin"
          render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}
        >
          {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/admin/summary" /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
```

2. Your private route is correct but need to add your layout as well:

```
return <AdminLayout {...props} /><Component {...props} /></AdminLayout/>;
```

3. Inside app route you need to import `PrivateRoute` component it will look like this:

```
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const alert = useSelector((state) => state.alert);
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.authentication.loggedIn);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/admin'>
          <YOUR AUTH COMPONENT WHICH YOU WANT TO RENDER />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <Route
          path='/auth/login'
          render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />}
        />
        <Route exact path='/auth/forgotPassword' component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path='/auth/mail_reset' component={MailReset} />
        <Redirect from='*' to='/auth/login' />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Here I created demo code of this. Take reference from it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-auth-forked-6q6o4?file=/example.js

Comment: thanks for the sandbox. I tried to implement your suggestions. But, couldn't get it to work. Tried your #2 even wrapping it around a fragment, still no luck. I've updated my description after trying your suggestions.

Comment: what is the issue coming? Can you plz add sandbox. It might be some minor mistake. Which is hard to read from this code. And sandbox help other developer to quickly debug the issue

Comment: Just create minimum barebore example what you are trying to do. You do not need to install redux any other extra libraries

Comment: yeah right. I'll do that. Issue it that it changes the URL but first it does not load the component and then when I refresh the page it loads a blank with `/admin/summary` URL.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-ride-k4igu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are exporting `PrivateRoute` wrong that why its giving error. Added and updated your sandbox. Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-fire-szql3?file=/src/Dashboard.js

Comment: here I have updated my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-morning-jvsl2?file=/src/Login.js with the `Login` that I am using and also, the reason why I am using `Layout` in routes is because`<AdminLayout/>` contains a whole lot of other stuff since its a SPA.